# Flutter button with url link under this text

Tags: flutter

Hi guys I would like to add button under this code
so that there will be redirection to a website.

```
class EmptyServiceSearch extends StatelessWidget {
  const EmptyServiceSearch({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return EmptyState(
      imageUrl: AppImages.emptySearch,
      title: "No Service/Provider Found".tr(),
      description: "There seems to be no Service/Provider".tr(),
      
    );
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a body under the description tag and then add a child to add `Elevated Button` which will give you a button... You can try to position the button in whichever manner you want to

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: onPressed, child: child),
```

Comment: I hve a red line in body , Onpress and Child

Comment: The onpress part is for adding a function that you want the button to perform, under the child you can add text that you want to be displayed in the button

Comment: do I need to set a package?

Comment: Apart from `import package:flutter/material. dart` no other package is required

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Stack` to achieve this.

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Button(),
    EmptyServiceSearch(),
  ],
)
```

If you want to add a button below, the you can use `Column` as following,

```
Column(
  children: [
    EmptyServiceSearch(),
    Button(),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Hi thank you I consider this one